# GPUImage failed to init ACVFile with data:(null)

Tags: ios, xcode, photoshop, gpuimage, curves

First of all, I must say that GPUImage is an excellent framework. However, when loading an ACV file that I export from Photoshop CS6, it gives me an error saying that: failed to init ACVFile with data:(null). The thing is though, that the same code works for some other ACV files, and the file definitely has data, 64 bites of it in fact.

Here is how I am trying to load it:

```html
GPUImageToneCurveFilter *stillImageFilter2 = [[GPUImageToneCurveFilter alloc] initWithACV:@"test"];
    UIImage *quickFilteredImage = [stillImageFilter2 imageByFilteringImage:baseImage];
    
    photoImage.image = quickFilteredImage;
```

If I change test to another ACV file, it works perfectly. Not sure what is wrong.

Thanks
MehtaiPhoneApps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the extension of tone curve file **test.acv** and you are good to go

=> updated code

```
GPUImageToneCurveFilter *stillImageFilter2 = [[GPUImageToneCurveFilter alloc] initWithACV:@"test.acv"];
UIImage *quickFilteredImage = [stillImageFilter2 imageByFilteringImage:baseImage];

photoImage.image = quickFilteredImage;
```