# GPUImage failed to init ACVFile with data:(null)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, photoshop, gpuimage

I downloaded a couple of .acv files off github to apply filters to an image but GPUImage always says that there is no data. I know my code is 100% right and the issue lies with the actual .acv files. Is there a specific way they need to be imported into Xcode?

I have already tried the solution offered here: [GPUImage failed to init ACVFile with data:(null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595445/gpuimage-failed-to-init-acvfile-with-datanull)

Answer (score 1):

After you drag your .acv in Xcode
[image]

Select the file.

check the file inspector and see if it has been added into the target.

I came across the same issue just now.
It won't be added in by default in my case.

Answer (score 0):

i have got same problem few days ago have you try adding .acv after test..

```
GPUImageToneCurveFilter *stillImageFilter2 = [[GPUImageToneCurveFilter alloc] initWithACV:@"test.acv"];
  UIImage *quickFilteredImage = [stillImageFilter2 imageByFilteringImage:baseImage];
  photoImage.image = quickFilteredImage;
```